# How $n\pi +(-1)^n \pi/6 = n\pi + \pi/6$ and $n\pi - (-1)^n \pi/6 = n\pi - \pi/6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm learning Trigonometry right now with myself and at current about general expression of the angles. I am confused in a problem from sometime . I don't know how $n\pi +(-1)^n \pi/6 = n\pi + \pi/6$ and $n\pi - (-1)^n \pi/6 = n\pi - \pi/6$. Please have a look at the images.
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: $(-1)^n = 1$ if $n$ is even and $(-1)^n = -1$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: S L loney in 2016

Comment: @Tim Is it bad for learning?

Comment: @YogeshTripathi No! I used it, but its quite old fashioned, and quite irrelevant at times. There are a lot of gaps missing out in theory.

Comment: Gaps like what?  I'm using it along with trigonometry book written by I.M.  Gelfand Mark Saul. What is your recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

You say "I don't know how $n\pi +(-1)^n \pi/6 = n\pi + \pi/6$ and $n\pi - (-1)^n \pi/6 = n\pi - \pi/6$" but this was never stated in your text.  It seems to me your problem is in understanding the last equation.

Is it clear to you why $\theta=n\pi\pm(-1)^n\pi/6$?  If so, then note that either $(-1)^n=1$ or $(-1)^n=-1$, depending on the value of $n$.  If it is the former, then $n\pi\pm(-1)^n\pi/6=n\pi\pm(-1)\pi/6=n\pi\mp\pi/6$.  If it is the latter, then $n\pi\pm(-1)^n\pi/6=n\pi\pm(1)\pi/6=n\pi\pm\pi/6$.

The first expression means $n\pi-\pi/6$ or $n\pi+\pi/6$.  The second expression means $n\pi+\pi/6$ or $n\pi-\pi/6$.  The two expressions mean the same thing.

Comment: Yes I have problem in the last equation. How nπ±(−1)π/6 and nπ±(1)π/6 are equal?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if $n$ is even $$\pm(-1)^n=\pm$$ 
and if $n$ is odd $$\pm(-1)^n=\mp.$$
The first case is clear. In the second case, the author means readily $n\pi+\frac\pi6$ or $n\pi-\frac\pi6$ and saying $n\pi-\frac\pi6$ or $n\pi+\frac\pi6$ is the same because $A$ or $B$ is the same as $B$ or $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

- $$(-1)^n=1\space\text{when}\space n\space\text{even}$$
- $$(-1)^n=-1\space\text{when}\space n\space\text{odd}$$

For the first one:

$$\sin^2\left(\theta\right)=\frac{1}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin\left(\theta\right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin\left(\theta\right)=\pm\frac{1}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\theta=\arcsin\left(\pm\frac{1}{2}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\theta=\pi n\pm\frac{\pi}{6}$$

With $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I think if n is Odd then *-* should be upper and *+* should be at below in the last line of the solution.